# Blank (white) page error running GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I'm experiencing a weird GWT error, there no compilation error however if I open the GWT app, its just white blank page, I looked into the browser console and I can see the app.nocache.js is loaded and no errors also.

What can I do to figure what's wrong, anyone have experienced this before?

Comment: Try running it in dev mode. It usually has a better description/stacktrace if something goes amiss

Comment: Maybe wrong target browser. It could be anything. Show some logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second the comments as above, show some error logs and also provide what ways have you tried to resolve this! :)

Few things that you could check in this case:

1. Clear your browser cache, close the browser and re-open
2. Ensure that you don't use any other external java script files before the GWT generated (applicationName).nocache.js
3. Ensure that you have a <!DOCTYPE html> tag in your html page, just so that you are not in Quirks mode
4. If you were using IE to render your application, check if you've accidentally hit 'Compatibility Mode' button

With the limited details that you provided, these are the possible solutions - Hope this helps!

Comment: Did any of the earlier suggestions worked for you? Did you clear the cache generated within your GWT project as well?

Comment: @xybrek, Did you do anything else other than this to resolve the issue? Please let me know if there is anything else that I missed!